# Why does water come out of this pipe when my kitchen sink is running?

Tags: basement

Water shoots out from the basement pipe when the kitchen sink is running.

I just bought this house a few months ago so I'm not familiar with these types of issues, very new.

[image]

Here’s a picture of the pipe where the water shoots out.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southland-3-4-in-Black-Malleable-Iron-Plug-Fitting-521-804HN/100075411 (not an endorsement, exactly). Get a 1" (and maybe bigger sizes) while you're there and return what you don't want. Use teflon tape or pipe dope ("rectorseal") to seal it up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it happens frequently.

Someone installed quick access to pressure clean the sewage line.

There is a part missing where to connect the water hose.

Since you have water coming out, that indicates the sewage pipe is starting to back up. Find the part missing or make one and pressure clean it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be threaded, maybe 1/2"bsp. Your local plumber's merchant will have a blank, with probably a square male on the outer end, to screw into the elbow. Maybe use some ptfe tape to seal better, and see what that does. That'd be my first move.

Answer (score 0):

I think that was a cleanout for the large pipe, then someone hacked it to install that metal elbow probably as a drain for something that has since been removed or broken off.

I suggest you remove that elbow and whatever it is attached to in the end of the large pipe, and buy a cleanout cover, that would have been there in the first place.

Assembling cast iron pipe isn't beginner DIY work ... maybe this is one for a plumber, unless what you have there is ready to accept a screw-on plug, that should be easy.

[image]

If there's a blockage further down the line, which we don't know for sure,  you'll need to open this up anyway in order to clean it out.